# Uncommon case in Arden's lemma $q_{2} = 1q_{2} \cup 0q_{2}$

Tags: automata, regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to get the regular expression of an automata but an state has a form that I don't know how to solve, the form on its simplest example is:
 $$q_{2} = 1q_{2} \cup 0q_{2}$$
What's the procedure to solve this form? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use $ax+bx=(a+b)x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!